# EPM 2010 Cannot delete project, checked out to admin in another session

Tags: ms-project-server-2010

In our Ms EPM 2010 setup, as an administrator I am unable to delete a project.

Initially, in order to delete,I had to check-in the project. When I did so, it showed me that the project is checked out to the admin account. When I logged in using that admin account, I coudlnt do anything as it says that its checked out to me/admin in another session.

When I open the project detail page for this project I see this on the top: 
Status: Checked-out to you in another session since 18/09/2014 10:17 Last Modified: 25/08/2014 09:40

Now I cant delete it, cant force check-in. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

I restarted the "Microsoft Project Server Queue Service 2010" service, first on the App Server and then the same named service on the Web Server. After that I checked if the project was checked in or not - it wasnt, it still was showing checked out to admin. I ignored it and opened the "Delete Enterprise Objects" page.

It worked this time!

So I am guessing that restarting the services did the trick!?